# How To Query Firestore to get Document by String Field (Search Engine Friendly Slug)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Component in React called `ShowArticle` and I am trying to query for a single document in `Firestore` in my `articles` collection by a string field called slug so that I can format my URLs as `//myhost.com/article/show/:slug` where slug is the matching, unique string in my Firestore.

As my Route I have:

`<Route exact path="/article/show/:slug" component={ShowArticle} />`

So I am getting the `:slug` parameter correctly with `const { slug } = props.match.params;` inside of `ShowArticle` component.

When I query the Firestore for a slug that exists in my database I receive no data back from Firestore.

How do I retrieve an Article document by a unique string value for SEF URLs?

My ShowArticle Component is as follows:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import Article from "./Article";

class ShowArticle extends Component {
  render() {
    const { article } = this.props;
    if (article) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Article
            key={article.id}
            title={article.title}
            date={article.date}
            body={article.body}
          />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )
    }
  }
}

ShowArticle.propTypes = {
  firestore: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default compose(
  firestoreConnect(props => {
    const { slug } = props.match.params;
    console.log(slug);
    return [
      {collection: 'articles', storeAs: 'article', doc: slug }
    ]
  }),
  connect(({ firestore: { ordered } }, props) => ({
    article: ordered.article && ordered.article[0]
  }))
)(ShowArticle);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the callback to `firestoreConnect()` change `doc: slug` to `queryParams: [ 'equalTo=' + slug ]`

So you will end up with:

```
export default compose(
  firestoreConnect(props => {
    const { slug } = props.match.params;
    console.log(slug);
    return [
      {collection: 'articles', storeAs: 'article', queryParams: [ 'equalTo=' + slug ] }
    ]
  }),
  connect(({ firestore: { ordered } }, props) => ({
    article: ordered.article && ordered.article[0]
  }))
)(ShowArticle);
```

Reference http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/queries.html#notParsed in the docs for the `react-redux-firebase` package.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using the latest version of React Router (v4+). Because in older React Router, it's the way to make available the id with the props. But in newer react-router library, you have to wrap the whole component with the "withRouter" higher-order component. It will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

At first, you have to import the withRouter.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

Then you have to wrap it with withRouter.

```
 export default withRouter(compose(
  firestoreConnect(props => {
    const { slug } = props.match.params;
    console.log(slug);
    return [
      {collection: 'articles', storeAs: 'article', doc: slug }
    ]
  }),
  connect(({ firestore: { ordered } }, props) => ({
    article: ordered.article && ordered.article[0]
  }))
)(ShowArticle))
```

This works for me like a charm!

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer to this question. Not really doing to much with Firestore anymore but it looks like this should work fine.